# How Many Characters in Linkedin company simple description API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

How many characters are in the LinkedIn company "simple description" of the API?

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/company-profile

Comment: What about the short description characters?

Comment: There is only one field about the `description` in Company API. Can you elaborate which short description characters you are talking about?

Comment: @RahulGupta I thought I saw somewhere.  You will see in the description here with "See More" drop down.  https://www.linkedin.com/company/165158

Comment: The 'See More' option you are talking about is just a slider made in frontend. It has nothing to with the API. In the API, there is just a `description` field having limit of 500 characters. This will return the complete description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be maximum of 500 characters in the Linkedin company `description` field received from the API.

From LinkedIn API [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/company-profile):

> description:
>   Company description. Limit of 500 characters.